# Google Maps Camera

Tags: ios, google-maps

I am working on `GMSMapView` integration in an iOS application where I want to integrate **GPS** like functionality.

I am done with the Map integration and also worked on the API's.

I am facing some issue with the camera. In Android, they provide some camera tilt option using which they can manage camera zoom level and camera angle.

Is there any option for camera tilt in the iOS application for Google Maps.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to google documentation:

```
let fancy = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: -33,
                                 longitude: 151,
                                 zoom: 6,
                                 bearing: 270,
                                 viewingAngle: 45)
mapView.camera = fancy
```

You can also change just an angle

```
mapView.animate(toViewingAngle: 45)
```

documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/views